# Understanding the idx column in h2o metrics

Tags: accuracy, reporting, pandas, h2o

h2o model metrics results report generated like this.

```
ModelMetricsBinomial: xgboost
** Reported on test data. **

MSE: 0.2027733882478528
RMSE: 0.45030366226342505
LogLoss: 0.5890830298889025
Mean Per-Class Error: 0.3520671274857333
AUC: 0.7466180668626095
AUCPR: 0.7385051498737671
Gini: 0.4932361337252189

Confusion Matrix (Act/Pred) for max f1 @ threshold = 0.3498794604902682: 
0   1      Error    Rate
0   0      3370.0   4427.0  0.5678  (4427.0/7797.0)
1   1      1045.0   6619.0  0.1364  (1045.0/7664.0)
2   Total  4415.0   11046.0 0.3539  (5472.0/15461.0)

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds

    metric                      threshold   value       idx

0   max f1                      0.349879    0.707536    272.0
1   max f2                      0.212350    0.840158    339.0
2   max f0point5                0.564374    0.692522    173.0
3   max accuracy                0.507255    0.693293    195.0
4   max precision               0.973586    1.000000    0.0
5   max recall                  0.041826    1.000000    396.0
6   max specificity             0.973586    1.000000    0.0
7   max absolute_mcc            0.507255    0.386543    195.0
8   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.505372    0.692328    196.0
9   max mean_per_class_accuracy 0.507255    0.693272    195.0
10  max tns                     0.973586    7797.000000 0.0
11  max fns                     0.973586    7660.000000 0.0
12  max fps                     0.021891    7797.000000 399.0
13  max tps                     0.041826    7664.000000 396.0
14  max tnr                     0.973586    1.000000    0.0
15  max fnr                     0.973586    0.999478    0.0
16  max fpr                     0.021891    1.000000    399.0
17  max tpr                     0.041826    1.000000    396.0
```

Can someone tell what `idx` stands for here?  Is it stands for `index`? Or it refers to number of items falls in that threshold.

For example, `max precision` says `0.973586` for threshold  `1.000000` for value and    `0.0` for idx.

I couldn't find any documentation for this. So can someone elaborate this?

Comment: Maybe more suitable to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered on stackoverflow in a [comment by Darren Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699454/how-to-understand-the-metrics-of-h2omodelmetrics-object-through-h2o-performance#comment95989085_43700476)

> It appears to be a 0..399 index into the bins used; i.e. it represents where on the x-axis of an AUC chart that optimal point is. See https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/745911ed1421592193451d9096f8640de1fa6d7a/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/AUC2.java#L104 and the definition of NBINS in that same file.